# How to append list of objects to Form Data and use it in Laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I need to send files to my server via ajax. Each file has its own description. I'm trying using array sand file and its description to the Laravel...

I tried to do this like:

```
jQuery.each(files, function(key, file) {
    var file = {
        'file': file,
        'desc': 'desc'
    };

    form_data.append('files[]', file);

    form_data.append('files[' + key + ']', file);
    form_data.append('files[' + key + ']description', 'desc');
});
```

Or like:

```
jQuery.each(files, function(key, file) {
    form_data.append('files[' + key + ']', file);
    form_data.append('files[' + key + ']description', 'desc');
});
```

On the server I'm trying to use it like `$files = $request->all(); dd($files);`. In the first case I get only array of descriptions. In the second js object name...

Comment: similar query which I am trying to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37097176/ajax-formdata-append-do-not-post-fileslaravel-4